# showMessageDialog influence KeyHandler

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have my KeyHandler here:

```
private void KeyHandler(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            if(menuPosition == 1){
                MenuLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/labyrinth grafika/menu/menu_volba_3.png")));
                menuPosition = 3;
            }
            else if(menuPosition == 2){
                MenuLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/labyrinth grafika/menu/menu_volba_1.png")));
                menuPosition = 1;
            }
            else if(menuPosition == 3){
                MenuLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/labyrinth grafika/menu/menu_volba_2.png")));
                menuPosition = 2;
            }
        }
        if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        {
            if(menuPosition == 1){
                MenuLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/labyrinth grafika/menu/menu_volba_2.png")));
                menuPosition = 2;
            }
            else if(menuPosition == 2){
                MenuLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/labyrinth grafika/menu/menu_volba_3.png")));
                menuPosition = 3;
            }
            else if(menuPosition == 3){
                MenuLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/labyrinth grafika/menu/menu_volba_1.png")));
                menuPosition = 1;
            }
        }
        if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        {
            if(menuPosition == 1){
                menuPosition = 5;
                Container parent = MenuLabel.getParent();
                parent.removeAll();
                parent.add(NewGamePanel);
                parent.repaint();
                parent.revalidate();

            }
            else if(menuPosition == 2){
                menuPosition = 4;
                MenuLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/labyrinth grafika/menu/readme.png")));
            }
            else if(menuPosition == 3){
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else if(menuPosition == 4){
                MenuLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/labyrinth grafika/menu/menu_volba_1.png")));
                menuPosition = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

and also I have my Button:

```
private void backButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        jPanel1.removeAll();
        jPanel1.add(MenuLabel);
        jPanel1.repaint();
        jPanel1.revalidate();
        menuPosition = 1;


    }
```

When JPanel1 is Panel of my program. I have CardLayout in there and when this button is clicked I wanna close everything and then get back to my MenuLabel.

In initComponents generated by Java there is this code:

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    MenuLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    NewGamePanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    NewGameHeader = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    NewGameBody = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    sizeOfField = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    sizeOfFieldLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    NewGameOkButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    numberOfPlayersCombo = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    backButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Labyrinth - The Game");
    setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 650));
    setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(650, 700));
    setResizable(false);
    setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(650, 700));
    addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            KeyHandler(evt);
        }
    });
    ...
```

Funny thing is, that my KeyHandler is not working after clicking the button, however when I put this simple code into the backButtonActionPerformed function:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, null);
```

the keyHandler is again working. Can anyone tell me why is that and how can I make the KeyHandler work again without poping a message dialog?

The rest of code is generated by Java (some other boxes etc.)

Thank you.

Comment: to what component have you added the `KeyListener`?

Comment: That keyListener is added to the jPanel1 which contains every other component. (there is MenuLabel and NewGamePanel which has another Label). But I am not sure 100% because its in initComponents function generated by Java/NetBeans... I will add more code to the original post.

Comment: what is the type of class in which you have implemented the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `backButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)` try adding a line

```
jPanel1.requestFocusInWindow();
```

before the line `menuPosition = 1;`  and try to run the program.

Comment: Sadly not working. But it may be the problem that the KeyBinding is to the whole JFrame. EDIT: I added the key Handler to the jPanel1 and now its working perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `KeyListener`s, the component they are registered to needs to have keyboard focus AND be focusable

Instead, use the Key Bindings API, which was designed to overcome these limitations

See [How to use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: So add to the Label Key Bindings and it should work properly?

Comment: You will need to add it to what ever component is controlling the menu. You may need to add it to several components, depending what you are trying to achieve